# Completely reset CSS “width” rule — Firefox bug?

Tags: css, firefox, layout

I’m facing a problem I cannot understand with Firefox 39.0.

I would like to *reset* the `width` of an element, but neither setting it to `auto` nor to `inherit` works.

```css
form input {
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
    <button>text</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

If I don’t set that I get the `width: 100%` from the general `input` styling.

The problem is that it overflows its container (**just on Firefox**) with that rule.

I tried to set `width: auto` but it reacts exacly the same as `inherit`. In the *Computed rules* section of the *Developer Tools* I can see that the *width* has a value in pixels.

**But** if I remove / uncheck all the `width` rules from the *Developer Tools* it reacts differently, and adapt its `width` exactly the way I want (that is, adapting to the real available dimensions; not more). In fact if I check the *Computed rules* section I see it now doesn’t have any `width` declaration!

I can achieve the same effect (of not having any `width` rule declared) setting the value to `unset`. But unfortunately the behaviour doesn’t change.

**How could I obtain the same?** Any value I tried doesn’t get that behaviour.
On all the other browsers it seems fine instead!

Comment: Try `width: unset;`.

Comment: I can’t even reproduce it. Try `!important`.

Comment: The code is part of a lot more complex page; I cannot include it. Btw I tried ```!important``` either on value ```auto``` and on ```unset``` but it keeps behaving the same. With ```unset``` it removes the rule from the *Computed rules* but the behaviour is not the same as when the rule is completely not declared :(

Comment: `width:auto` or `width:unset` should have done the trick. If it doesn't work, something is wrong. Note that `width:inherit` won't work; this sets the width to the same width as the parent, which, if the parent has no width defined, will be `auto` by default. This would accidentally turn out OK.  But if the parent has `width:300px` then the width of the input would also become 300px!

Comment: @MrLister Yes you are right about ```inherit```, it was the last try I was done but it is the incorrect choice.
I just discovered that the bugs shows **just if Firefox is zoomed to its default size!** All the other (major or minor) sizes don't have the problem! O_O

Comment: @MrLister unfortunately I always work with the *Developer Tools* "Disable cache" option enabled.

Comment: I'm re-reading your question now and I'm not sure I understand everything. What is the exact behaviour that you're trying to obtain? You say "the behaviour doesn't change", but from what to what should it change? You do get the default width, right? So what else should happen?

Comment: The code is just a part so there are other stylings, i want to reset, applied by default to the *input*. But regardless that, on Firefox it has the weird behaviour described above. Just happens that if I disable all the present rules for ```width``` I get a behaviour (width to the available space), but instead resetting the value to ```unset``` or ```auto``` doesn't behave the same as not setting at all the ```width```. My question is not about having a specific behaviour (I already solved in other ways) but just about the inconsistent behaviour of Firefox with a *set rule* and a *reset rule*.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem only in Firefox. I have an input, let's say x%. But inside a certain container, I want to let it be its "default" size. I tried with `width:auto !imortant`, with unset, with inherit, all combinations. It does not return to what it should be the default size. If I, however, uncheck all "width" statements in development tools, it sizes as I wanted. This is working properly in IE11 and Chrome...but not in Firefox